# Android Webview crash when url requests for location thru javascript in Froyo

Tags: android, webview, geolocation, webkit

I have a webview and it crashes the moment i go to a page where a javascript requests permission to use its location. By the way, this happens only on devices running Froyo.

Here's the logcat:

```
Ljava/lang/RuntimeException;: Unable to instantiate Application():java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.attach(ActivityThread.java:4571)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.systemMain(ActivityThread.java:4606)
    at android.webkit.GeolocationService.<init>(GeolocationService.java:54)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.nativeFinished(Native Method)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.tearDown(LoadListener.java:1200)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleEndData(LoadListener.java:721)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleMessage(LoadListener.java:219)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:621)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
Caused by:
Ljava/lang/NullPointerException;:
    at android.content.res.Resources.updateConfiguration(Resources.java:1337)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.getSystemContext(ActivityThread.java:2417)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.attach(ActivityThread.java:4565)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.systemMain(ActivityThread.java:4606)
    at android.webkit.GeolocationService.<init>(GeolocationService.java:54)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.nativeFinished(Native Method)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.tearDown(LoadListener.java:1200)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleEndData(LoadListener.java:721)
    at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleMessage(LoadListener.java:219)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:621)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
 "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=15 NATIVE
   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x440fe658 self=0x3c37b0
   | sysTid=480 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3946736
   | schedstat=( 23740425422 6099590333 2085 )
   at android.webkit.LoadListener.nativeFinished(Native Method)
   at android.webkit.LoadListener.tearDown(LoadListener.java:1200)
   at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleEndData(LoadListener.java:721)
   at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleMessage(LoadListener.java:219)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:621)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: May be your location is null.post some code where you got these exception.

Comment: I just have a basic activity with a webview with the following settings:

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(path);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
/* override methods */
}
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
/* override methods */
}